# MongoDB how we can group data by field value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following query, what I want is to have a combined group of custom group field names, with field value.

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([
  {"$match":{
     "expireDate":{"$gte":"2018-02-06T00:00:00.000Z"},
     "publishDate":{"$lte":"2018-02-06T00:00:00.000Z"},
     "isPublished":true,"isDrafted":false,
     "deletedAt":{"$eq":null},"deleted":false
  }},
  {"$group":{
     "twentyFourHourAgo":{
        "$sum":{
           "$cond":[
             {"$gt":["$publishDate","2018-02-04T08:48:16.892Z"]},1,0
           ]
        }
      },
      "fortyEightHourAgo":{
        "$sum":{
            "$cond":[
               {"$gt":["$publishDate","2018-02-01T08:48:16.892Z"]},1,0
            ]
        }
      },
      "thirtyDaysAgo":{
         "$sum":{
            "$cond":[
               {"$gt":["$publishDate","2017-12-31T08:48:16.892Z"]},1,0
            ]
         }
      },
      "_id":{
        "position":{"$ifNull":["$position","Unknown"]},
        "workType":{"$ifNull":["$workType","Unknown"]},
        "functionalArea":{"$ifNull":["$functionalArea","Unknown"]},
        "minimumEducation":{"$ifNull":["$minimumEducation","Unknown"]},
        "gender":{"$ifNull":["$gender","Unknown"]},
        "contractType":{"$ifNull":["$contractType","Unknown"]},
        "locations":{"$ifNull":["$locations","Unknown"]},
        "requiredLanguages":{"$ifNull":["$requiredLanguages","Unknown"]},
        "company":{"$ifNull":["$company.name","Unknown"]}},"count":{"$sum":1}
     }
 },
 {"$group":{
     "_id":null,
     "twentyFourHourAgo":{
        "$sum":"twentyFourHourAgo"
     },
     "fortyEightHourAgo":{
        "$sum":"$fortyEightHourAgo"
     },
     "thirtyDaysAgo":{
        "$sum":"$thirtyDaysAgo"
     },
     "position":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.position","Count":"$count"}},
     "workType":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.workType","Count":"$count"}},
     "functionalArea":{
        "$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.functionalArea","Count":"$count"}
     },
     "minimumEducation":{
        "$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.minimumEducation","Count":"$count"}
     },
     "gender":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.gender","Count":"$count"}},"contractType":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.contractType","Count":"$count"}},"locations":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.locations","Count":"$count"}},"requiredLanguages":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.requiredLanguages","Count":"$count"}},"company":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.company","Count":"$count"}}}}]  
)
```

my document inside collection schema is like:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e4540bf14f1607b90ffb81"),
    "vacancyNumber" : "1",
    "position" : "Software Tester",
    "publishDate" : ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "expireDate" : ISODate("2018-05-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "yearsOfExperience" : 40,
    "minimumEducation" : "Doctorate",
    "functionalArea" : "Education",
    "company" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("59e453fbf14f1607b90ffb80"),
        "name" : "First Company",
        "profile" : "profile",
        "logo" : {
            "container" : "companyFiles",
            "name" : "abbbff58cd3fda2c59ab2ee620ea5aa0",
            "mime" : ".png",
            "size" : 5806
        }
    },
    "durations" : {
        "years" : 3,
        "months" : 4
    },
    "probationPeriod" : {
        "duration" : 34,
        "unit" : "month"
    },
    "salary" : {
        "minSalary" : 1000,
        "maxSalary" : 2000,
        "currency" : "USD",
        "period" : "monthly",
        "isNegotiable" : true
    },
    "locations" : [ 
        "Germany", 
        "Itly", 
        "Iran"
    ],
    "canApplyOnline" : true,
    "skills" : [ 
        "Skill1", 
        "Skill2", 
        "Skill3", 
        "Skill4"
    ],
    "requiredLanguages" : [ 
        "Arabic", 
        "English", 
        "Russian", 
        "Dari", 
        "French"
    ],
    "keywords" : [ 
        "Key1", 
        "Key2"
    ],
    "deleted" : false,
    "deletedAt" : null,
    "isDrafted" : false,
    "isPublished" : true,
    "requiresTravel" : true,
    "gender" : "male",
    "nationalities" : [ 
        "afghan"
    ],
    "workType" : "Full Time",
    "contractType" : "Permanent",
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f9402e05d04ebe5653d98f"),
    "vacancyNumber" : "1",
    "position" : "Software Engineer",
    "publishDate" : ISODate("2018-01-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "expireDate" : ISODate("2018-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "yearsOfExperience" : 40,
    "minimumEducation" : "Doctorate",
    "functionalArea" : "Education",
    "company" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("59e453fbf14f1607b90ffb80"),
        "name" : "First Company",
        "profile" : "profile",
        "logo" : {
            "container" : "logo container",
            "name" : "logo name",
            "mime" : "logo mime type",
            "size" : 1
        }
    },    
    "durations" : {
        "years" : 3,
        "months" : 4
    },
    "probationPeriod" : {
        "duration" : 34,
        "unit" : "month"
    },
    "salary" : {
        "minSalary" : 1000,
        "maxSalary" : 2000,
        "currency" : "USD",
        "period" : "monthly",
        "isNegotiable" : true
    },
    "locations" : [ 
        "Afghanistan", 
        "Itly", 
        "Iran"
    ],
    "skills" : [ 
        "Skill1", 
        "Another Skill"
    ],
    "requiredLanguages" : [ 
        "Arabic", 
        "English", 
        "Russian", 
        "Dari", 
        "French"
    ],
    "keywords" : [ 
        "Keyword", 
        "Key1"
    ],
    "deleted" : false,
    "deletedAt" : null,
    "isDrafted" : false,
    "isPublished" : true,
    "gender" : "male",
    "nationalities" : [ 
        "afghan", 
        "iranian"
    ],
    "workType" : "Full Time",
    "contractType" : "Short-Term",
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a03235234f7504f13970abd"),
    "vacancyNumber" : "1",
    "position" : "Software Tester",
    "publishDate" : ISODate("2017-10-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "expireDate" : ISODate("2018-11-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "yearsOfExperience" : 40,
    "minimumEducation" : "Doctorate",
    "functionalArea" : "IT Software",
    "company" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("59e453fbf14f1607b90ffb80"),
        "name" : "My First Company",
        "profile" : "profile",
        "logo" : {
            "container" : "logo container",
            "name" : "logo name",
            "mime" : "logo mime type",
            "size" : 1
        }
    },
    "durations" : {
        "years" : 3,
        "months" : 4
    },
    "probationPeriod" : {
        "duration" : 34,
        "unit" : "month"
    },
    "salary" : {
        "minSalary" : 1000,
        "maxSalary" : 2000,
        "currency" : "USD",
        "period" : "monthly",
        "isNegotiable" : true
    },
    "locations" : [ 
        "Germany", 
        "Itly", 
        "Iran"
    ],
    "skills" : [ 
        "Skill1", 
        "Test Skill"
    ],
    "requiredLanguages" : [ 
        "Arabic", 
        "English", 
        "Russian", 
        "Dari", 
        "French"
    ],
    "keywords" : [ 
        "Test Key", 
        "Keyword"
    ],
    "deleted" : false,
    "deletedAt" : null,
    "isDrafted" : false,
    "isPublished" : true,
    "gender" : "female",
    "nationalities" : [ 
        "afghan"
    ],
    "workType" : "Part Time",
    "contractType" : "Permanent",
}
```

Now I want to count the group of data by my custom expression check 'twentyFourHourAgo, fortyEightHourAgo, thirtyDaysAgo', and also by the value of a field (`functionalArea, position, locations, keywords, workType`).

My current query result is

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "twentyFourHourAgo" : 0,
    "fortyEightHourAgo" : 0.0,
    "thirtyDaysAgo" : 2.0,
    "position" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Software Engineer",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Software Tester",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "workType" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Full Time",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Part Time",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "functionalArea" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Education",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "IT Software",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "minimumEducation" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Doctorate",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "gender" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "male",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "female",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "contractType" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Short-Term",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Permanent",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "locations" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : [ 
                "Afghanistan", 
                "Itly", 
                "Iran"
            ],
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : [ 
                "Germany", 
                "Itly", 
                "Iran"
            ],
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "requiredLanguages" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : [ 
                "Arabic", 
                "English", 
                "Russian", 
                "Dari", 
                "French"
            ],
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "company" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "First Company",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "My First Company",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see, I have three document that has following properties:

1. Two document that has the same position `Software Tester`, but query return `1 Software Tester` (It means if I have multiple documents that have some common values in specific columns, their count result is wrong). The same problem exists for other fields 'contractType, workType, etc...'.
2. In array-type fields such as `locations`, my first document has `Germany, Italy, Iran` values in `locations` array, my second document has `Afghanistan, Italy, Iran`, and my third document has `Germany, Italy, Iran`. But query result is like this:

   ```
   "locations" : [ 
     {
       "Name" : [ 
         "Afghanistan", 
         "Itly", 
         "Iran"
       ],
       "Count" : 1.0
     }, 
     {
       "Name" : [ 
         "Germany", 
         "Itly", 
         "Iran"
       ],
       "Count" : 1.0
     }
    ],
   ```

This should be like: `Germany => 2, Italy,Iran => 3, and Afghanistan => 1`
The same problem exists for other array type fields.

Comment: `publishDate` "seems" to be a date field (seems because you don't have the field in your example document) but you are comparing it with a string in the expression `{"$gte":["$publishDate","2018-01-30T19:30:00.000Z"]}`. Have you tried casting the string to date, as in `{"$gte":["$publishDate",ISODate("2018-01-30T19:30:00.000Z")]}`?

Comment: @chridam yeah its date, I have missed this here.

Comment: @N3i1 My document structure is the same I have posted, except I have forgotten date fields, Now you can check my question. Any extra info you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This give you what you were asking:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
 {"$match":{
        "expireDate":{"$gte": ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z")},
        "publishDate":{"$lte": ISODate("2018-05-29T00:00:00.000Z")},
        "isPublished":true,"isDrafted":false,
        "deletedAt":{"$eq":null},
        "deleted":false
    }},
    {"$group":{
        "twentyFourHourAgo":{
            "$sum":{
                "$cond":[
                    {"$gte":["$publishDate", ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z")]},1,0
                ]
            }
        },
        "fortyEightHourAgo":{
            "$sum":{
                "$cond":[
                    {"$gte":["$publishDate", ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z")]},1,0
                ]
            }
        },
        "thirtyDaysAgo":{
            "$sum":{
                "$cond":[
                    {"$gte":["$publishDate", ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z")]},1,0
                ]
            }
        },
        "_id":{
            "$ifNull":["$functionalArea","Unknown"]
        }, 
        /* Changes start from here */
        "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } },
        { "$group" : { 
            "_id" : "null", "fortyEightHourAgo" : { "$sum" : "$fortyEightHourAgo"}, 
            "thirtyDaysAgo" : { "$sum" : "$thirtyDaysAgo"},  
            "twentyFourHourAgo" : { "$sum" : "$twentyFourHourAgo"},  
            "functionalArea" : { "$addToSet" : { "Name": "$_id", "Count" : "$count" } } }}
])
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "fortyEightHourAgo" : 3.0,
    "thirtyDaysAgo" : 3.0,
    "twentyFourHourAgo" : 3.0,
    "functionalArea" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Education",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "IT Software",
            "Count" : 2.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But what I want is not taking `funcioinalArea` by `_id` field, and also not two document as result, because the count of data by date will be divided into two part with your query. My query also returns the same result.

Comment: @jones by `grouping` on `funcioinalArea` as your `_id` you'll cause that to happen

Comment: Yeah, but what I want is, to find a way to solve this.

Comment: @jones Please see my updated answer. I believe this is what you're after

Comment: This one is almost what I want, but one problem still exists, I have some other fields like `functionalArea` that I should have in the query, some of them are array, and some of them are same as `functionalArea`.

Comment: @jones Update your OP with an example of what you want your exact output to look like.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed some parts and solved my problems.

Comment: Once again disturb you, sorry for this, I have updated my question, and posted my data, still query return wrong result. Please help to solve this. Thank u. Because to encourage others to see my question as an active one, I should get back my acceptance from your answer, big sorry for this also.

Comment: So I answer your question and you mark it as correct. Now you’ve decided to change your OP and mark my answer as incorrect as a result! Nice!! Surely the right thing would have been to raise a new OP. Very noble

Comment: No, just my complete data was not in my previous question, but no problem I will submit a new question, and mark your answer.

Comment: As you told, I have created new question, so please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656837/mongodb-group-by-multiple-fields-in-a-way-to-not-affect-each-other-result

Comment: pls help if you can for related questions in mongoDB - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067856/calculate-dwell-time-between-2-statuses-of-a-field