# MongoDB group by multiple fields in a way to not affect each other result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following query, what I want is to have a combined group of custom group field names, with field value.

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([
  {"$match":{
     "expireDate":{"$gte":"2018-02-06T00:00:00.000Z"},
     "publishDate":{"$lte":"2018-02-06T00:00:00.000Z"},
     "isPublished":true,"isDrafted":false,
     "deletedAt":{"$eq":null},"deleted":false
  }},
  {"$group":{
     "twentyFourHourAgo":{
        "$sum":{
           "$cond":[
             {"$gt":["$publishDate","2018-02-04T08:48:16.892Z"]},1,0
           ]
        }
      },
      "fortyEightHourAgo":{
        "$sum":{
            "$cond":[
               {"$gt":["$publishDate","2018-02-01T08:48:16.892Z"]},1,0
            ]
        }
      },
      "thirtyDaysAgo":{
         "$sum":{
            "$cond":[
               {"$gt":["$publishDate","2017-12-31T08:48:16.892Z"]},1,0
            ]
         }
      },
      "_id":{
        "position":{"$ifNull":["$position","Unknown"]},
        "workType":{"$ifNull":["$workType","Unknown"]},
        "functionalArea":{"$ifNull":["$functionalArea","Unknown"]},
        "minimumEducation":{"$ifNull":["$minimumEducation","Unknown"]},
        "gender":{"$ifNull":["$gender","Unknown"]},
        "contractType":{"$ifNull":["$contractType","Unknown"]},
        "locations":{"$ifNull":["$locations","Unknown"]},
        "requiredLanguages":{"$ifNull":["$requiredLanguages","Unknown"]},
        "company":{"$ifNull":["$company.name","Unknown"]}},"count":{"$sum":1}
     }
 },
 {"$group":{
     "_id":null,
     "twentyFourHourAgo":{
        "$sum":"twentyFourHourAgo"
     },
     "fortyEightHourAgo":{
        "$sum":"$fortyEightHourAgo"
     },
     "thirtyDaysAgo":{
        "$sum":"$thirtyDaysAgo"
     },
     "position":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.position","Count":"$count"}},
     "workType":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.workType","Count":"$count"}},
     "functionalArea":{
        "$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.functionalArea","Count":"$count"}
     },
     "minimumEducation":{
        "$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.minimumEducation","Count":"$count"}
     },
     "gender":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.gender","Count":"$count"}},"contractType":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.contractType","Count":"$count"}},"locations":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.locations","Count":"$count"}},"requiredLanguages":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.requiredLanguages","Count":"$count"}},"company":{"$addToSet":{"Name":"$_id.company","Count":"$count"}}}}]  
)
```

my document inside collection schema is like:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e4540bf14f1607b90ffb81"),
    "vacancyNumber" : "1",
    "position" : "Software Tester",
    "publishDate" : ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "expireDate" : ISODate("2018-05-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "yearsOfExperience" : 40,
    "minimumEducation" : "Doctorate",
    "functionalArea" : "Education",
    "company" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("59e453fbf14f1607b90ffb80"),
        "name" : "First Company",
        "profile" : "profile",
        "logo" : {
            "container" : "companyFiles",
            "name" : "abbbff58cd3fda2c59ab2ee620ea5aa0",
            "mime" : ".png",
            "size" : 5806
        }
    },
    "durations" : {
        "years" : 3,
        "months" : 4
    },
    "probationPeriod" : {
        "duration" : 34,
        "unit" : "month"
    },
    "salary" : {
        "minSalary" : 1000,
        "maxSalary" : 2000,
        "currency" : "USD",
        "period" : "monthly",
        "isNegotiable" : true
    },
    "locations" : [ 
        "Germany", 
        "Itly", 
        "Iran"
    ],
    "canApplyOnline" : true,
    "skills" : [ 
        "Skill1", 
        "Skill2", 
        "Skill3", 
        "Skill4"
    ],
    "requiredLanguages" : [ 
        "Arabic", 
        "English", 
        "Russian", 
        "Dari", 
        "French"
    ],
    "keywords" : [ 
        "Key1", 
        "Key2"
    ],
    "deleted" : false,
    "deletedAt" : null,
    "isDrafted" : false,
    "isPublished" : true,
    "requiresTravel" : true,
    "gender" : "male",
    "nationalities" : [ 
        "afghan"
    ],
    "workType" : "Full Time",
    "contractType" : "Permanent",
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f9402e05d04ebe5653d98f"),
    "vacancyNumber" : "1",
    "position" : "Software Engineer",
    "publishDate" : ISODate("2018-01-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "expireDate" : ISODate("2018-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "yearsOfExperience" : 40,
    "minimumEducation" : "Doctorate",
    "functionalArea" : "Education",
    "company" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("59e453fbf14f1607b90ffb80"),
        "name" : "First Company",
        "profile" : "profile",
        "logo" : {
            "container" : "logo container",
            "name" : "logo name",
            "mime" : "logo mime type",
            "size" : 1
        }
    },    
    "durations" : {
        "years" : 3,
        "months" : 4
    },
    "probationPeriod" : {
        "duration" : 34,
        "unit" : "month"
    },
    "salary" : {
        "minSalary" : 1000,
        "maxSalary" : 2000,
        "currency" : "USD",
        "period" : "monthly",
        "isNegotiable" : true
    },
    "locations" : [ 
        "Afghanistan", 
        "Itly", 
        "Iran"
    ],
    "skills" : [ 
        "Skill1", 
        "Another Skill"
    ],
    "requiredLanguages" : [ 
        "Arabic", 
        "English", 
        "Russian", 
        "Dari", 
        "French"
    ],
    "keywords" : [ 
        "Keyword", 
        "Key1"
    ],
    "deleted" : false,
    "deletedAt" : null,
    "isDrafted" : false,
    "isPublished" : true,
    "gender" : "male",
    "nationalities" : [ 
        "afghan", 
        "iranian"
    ],
    "workType" : "Full Time",
    "contractType" : "Short-Term",
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a03235234f7504f13970abd"),
    "vacancyNumber" : "1",
    "position" : "Software Tester",
    "publishDate" : ISODate("2017-10-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "expireDate" : ISODate("2018-11-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "yearsOfExperience" : 40,
    "minimumEducation" : "Doctorate",
    "functionalArea" : "IT Software",
    "company" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("59e453fbf14f1607b90ffb80"),
        "name" : "My First Company",
        "profile" : "profile",
        "logo" : {
            "container" : "logo container",
            "name" : "logo name",
            "mime" : "logo mime type",
            "size" : 1
        }
    },
    "durations" : {
        "years" : 3,
        "months" : 4
    },
    "probationPeriod" : {
        "duration" : 34,
        "unit" : "month"
    },
    "salary" : {
        "minSalary" : 1000,
        "maxSalary" : 2000,
        "currency" : "USD",
        "period" : "monthly",
        "isNegotiable" : true
    },
    "locations" : [ 
        "Germany", 
        "Itly", 
        "Iran"
    ],
    "skills" : [ 
        "Skill1", 
        "Test Skill"
    ],
    "requiredLanguages" : [ 
        "Arabic", 
        "English", 
        "Russian", 
        "Dari", 
        "French"
    ],
    "keywords" : [ 
        "Test Key", 
        "Keyword"
    ],
    "deleted" : false,
    "deletedAt" : null,
    "isDrafted" : false,
    "isPublished" : true,
    "gender" : "female",
    "nationalities" : [ 
        "afghan"
    ],
    "workType" : "Part Time",
    "contractType" : "Permanent",
}
```

Now I want to count the group of data by my custom expression check 'twentyFourHourAgo, fortyEightHourAgo, thirtyDaysAgo', and also by the value of a field (`functionalArea, position, locations, keywords, workType`).

My current query result is

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "twentyFourHourAgo" : 0,
    "fortyEightHourAgo" : 0.0,
    "thirtyDaysAgo" : 2.0,
    "position" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Software Engineer",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Software Tester",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "workType" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Full Time",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Part Time",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "functionalArea" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Education",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "IT Software",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "minimumEducation" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Doctorate",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "gender" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "male",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "female",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "contractType" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Short-Term",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Permanent",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "locations" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : [ 
                "Afghanistan", 
                "Itly", 
                "Iran"
            ],
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : [ 
                "Germany", 
                "Itly", 
                "Iran"
            ],
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "requiredLanguages" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : [ 
                "Arabic", 
                "English", 
                "Russian", 
                "Dari", 
                "French"
            ],
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "company" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "First Company",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "My First Company",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see, I have three document that has following properties:

1. Two document that has the same position `Software Tester`, but query return `1 Software Tester` (It means if I have multiple documents that have some common values in specific columns, their count result is wrong). The same problem exists for other fields 'contractType, workType, etc...'.
2. In array-type fields such as `locations`, my first document has `Germany, Italy, Iran` values in `locations` array, my second document has `Afghanistan, Italy, Iran`, and my third document has `Germany, Italy, Iran`. But query result is like this:

   ```
   "locations" : [ 
     {
       "Name" : [ 
         "Afghanistan", 
         "Itly", 
         "Iran"
       ],
       "Count" : 1.0
     }, 
     {
       "Name" : [ 
         "Germany", 
         "Itly", 
         "Iran"
       ],
       "Count" : 1.0
     }
    ],
   ```

This should be like: `Germany => 2, Italy,Iran => 3, and Afghanistan => 1`
The same problem exists for other array type fields.

Comment: You need to use `$unwind` on each array element before your `$group`. This will enable you to then count all the elements within each array

Comment: @N3i1 I have tried that, but with `$unwind`, other fields affect and return the wrong result for other fields, I have tried that with `locations` field.

Comment: I cannot see in your above OP the `$unwind` being used. Please see my below answer

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I misunderstood your question earlier. To be able to `$unwind` the `location` array, but NOT effect your `twentyFourHourAgo` etc you could look at using `$first`.

You'll need to `$unwind` any array if you wish count/sum  the individual elements.

Example of how using `$first`.

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
{ $unwind : "$locations" },
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", 
        "twentyFourHourAgo":{ $first : {
            "$sum" : { "$cond":[
                {"$gt":["$publishDate", ISODate("2016-10-10T00:00:00.000Z")]},1,0 ] } } },
        "fortyEightHourAgo" : { $first : {
            "$sum" : { "$cond" : [ 
                { "$gt" : [ "$publishDate","2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"]},1,0 ] } } },
        "thirtyDaysAgo" : { $first : { 
            "$sum" : { "$cond" : [
                { "$gt" : [ "$publishDate","2017-12-31T08:48:16.892Z"]},1,0 ] } } },
        } },
{ "$group" : { "_id" : null,
     "twentyFourHourAgo" : { "$sum" : "$twentyFourHourAgo" },
     "fortyEightHourAgo" : { "$sum" : "$fortyEightHourAgo" },
     "thirtyDaysAgo" : { "$sum" : "$thirtyDaysAgo" },
 }}
])
```

Output:

```
"_id" : null,
"twentyFourHourAgo" : 0,
"fortyEightHourAgo" : 3.0,
"thirtyDaysAgo" : 3.0,
```

Please see here [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/index.html) for further information on why I think it might be of use. I've stuck an `$unwind` at the beginning to help prove that it will solve the problem in your OP.

Comment: As you see, this change result in other fields, I have three document, but result is like `"twentyFourHourAgo" : 0,
    "fortyEightHourAgo" : 9.0,
    "thirtyDaysAgo" : 9.0,
 `

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I was trying to highlight the need to`$unwind` inorder to fix your `count` problem! Have you tried `$projection` to project the values of `twentyFourHourAgo`, `fortyEightHourAgo` and `thirtyDaysAgo` as to not interfere with your groupings?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried, but I couldn't  used that with the group.